# Not able to install latest version of dependencies of React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, mern

I have cloned a project from GitHub and trying to install dependencies using `npm install` but it throws error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: 3dfolio@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-beta || ^16.0.0" from react-tilt@0.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tilt
npm ERR!   react-tilt@"^0.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Gyan Prakash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gyan Prakash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-06T18_09_10_160Z-debug-0.log
```

there is any method to resolve this error.

Comment: Have you tried including the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag as the error output suggested? Sounds like that project has some dependencies that need to be updated.

Comment: I have tried this flag (--legacy-peer-deps) and it worked, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-tilt@0.1.4` package has below peer dependencies

```
$ npm view react-tilt@0.1.4 peerDependencies
{
  react: '^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-beta || ^16.0.0',
  'react-dom': '^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-beta || ^16.0.0'
}
```

But in your project, the installed `react` version is `^18.2.0` which is incompatible with the version specified in `peerDependency`.

Two safe solutions:

- Downgrading the `react` package to those compatible versions.

```
npm i react@^16.14.0 react-dom@^16.14.0 -S
```

Then, install the `react-tilt@^0.1.4`:

```
$ npm i react-tilt@^0.1.4 -S

up to date, audited 10 packages in 1s
```

The warning is gone. List the installed package:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
peer-deps-issue@ /home/lindu/workspace/peer-deps-issue
├── react-dom@16.14.0
├── react-tilt@0.1.4
└── react@16.14.0
```

- Upgrading the `react-tilt` package to the latest version(1.0.2 until 2023.7.4) which is compatible with `React 18.x`.

```
$ npm view react-tilt@1.0.2 peerDependencies
{
  '@types/react': '^18.0.29',
  '@types/react-dom': '^18.0.11',
  react: '^18.2.0',
  'react-dom': '^18.2.0'
}
```

Install the latest version of the `react-tilt` package.

```
$ npm i react-tilt -S
```

List the installed packages:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
peer-deps-issue@ /home/lindu/workspace/peer-deps-issue
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react-tilt@1.0.2
└── react@18.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

// Run

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

add --legacy-peer-deps at the end of your npm command like below

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
npm i --force
```